# Dealing with views and recursion

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is my code

classA.h

```
#import classB.h

@interface classA : UIViewController
{
  classB *classb;
}

@property (nonatimic, retain) classB *classb;
@end
```

classA.m

```
@implementation classA
@synthesize classb = _classb;

-(void)someMethod
{
  self.classb = [[classb alloc]initWithNibName:@"classb" bundle:nil];
  [self.view.superview addSubview:self.classb.view]; 
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];

}
@end
```

That code work well. classb view is loaded normally. The problem starts here

classB.h

```
#import classA.h

    @interface classB: UIViewController
    {
       classA *classa;
    }
    @property (nonatimic, retain) classA *classa;
    @end
```

Now in classA I get error

```
Unknown type name classB;
```

I think the problem is some kind of recursion. 
The idea is classA to load classB view and in some point classB to remove self from superview and add classA as view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the `#import classA.h` from `classB.h` to `classB.m` and add `@class classA` to the header file of classB

If you use a class only in an `@interface` (i.e. you don't use a `@protocol` defined in that class header) it's enough to use the `@class SomeClass` statement.

This will prevent circular includes.

---

classB.h:

```
@class classA;

@interface classB: UIViewController
{
   classA *classa;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) classA *classa;

@end
```

classB.m:

```
#import "classB.h";
#import "classA.h";

@implementation classB 
/* */
@end
```